# Adding partial etha-squared column to tbl_regression object in R

Tags: r, regression, gtsummary

I would like to add a column to my tbl_regression object that show's the partial etha-squared values for each predictor in my model (i.e. not for each 'level' but for each 'label').

My first attempt was trying to do add the column using modify_table_body, like so:

```
summary(trauma_model_all)

partial_eta2 <- eta_squared(trauma_model_all)
interpret_omega_squared(partial_eta2, rules = "cohen1992")

trauma_tbl_all <- tbl_regression(trauma_model_all) %>%
  add_global_p() %>%
  bold_p(t = 0.10) %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  italicize_levels() %>%
  # adding number of non-events to table
  modify_table_body(
    ~ .x %>%
      dplyr::mutate(N_nonevent = partial_eta2$Eta2_partial)
  ) %>%
  # assigning header labels
  modify_header(N_nonevent = "**Control N**") %>%
  modify_fmt_fun(c(N_nonevent) ~ style_number)
```

This throws the error: Error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `dplyr::mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `N_nonevent = partial_eta2$Eta2_partial`.
Caused by error:
! `N_nonevent` must be size 124 or 1, not 43.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Probably because it tries to map my etha values to each level, not each label in the table. How do I work around that? Is there another way of achieving what I'm trying to do here? From what I'm seeing, the add_stat() command doesn't work for tbl_regression objects. I would potentially like to use a different effect size measure in the future (i.e. something other than etha), so the answer doesn't have to be specific to etha.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please update your post with code we can run on our machines (which includes data), aka minimal reprex or reproducible example. https://reprex.tidyverse.org/